# Prevent windows Shutdown with CANCEL option C#

Tags: c#, windows, shutdown

I'm trying to include in my Windows Form App a way that when user tries to shutdown windows it opens a dialog box with **CANCEL** option....that office classic one.

In other topics, people describes how to prevent windows shutdown. They use a dialog box for this. It helps but if the user **immediately** clicks in any option in this box, windows closes the application.

You can understand what I'm meaning, doing the following test:

In windows Vista or 7 Open Paint, Word or any office soft and begin writing something. Do not save it.

Try to shutdown windows and when the classic save dialog box appears **IMMEDIATELY** click in "cancel".

You will see that the application continues to work and windows is asking you what you want to do.

I tried to follow this [Microsoft Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx) but if I click "ok" in Message Box, the App closes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.WindowsShutDown))
        {
           if (MessageBox.Show("You are closing this app.\n\nAre you sure you wish to exit ?", "Warning: Not Submitted", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop) == DialogResult.Yes)
               return;    
           else    
               e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bibhu it worked!
</br>
But you forgot to initialize the event:

this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);

One more question: how can I edit the windows vista and 7 message: "This program is preventing windows from logging off"?

Answer (score 0):

Although delay windows shutdown is not recommended it is possible using shutdown scripts. You can configure your own script file using gpedit.msc configuration file.
I have read that these scripts can delay the windows shutdown up to 10 minutes.

I hope it helps